# ASP.NET MVC - Getting a Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC app. In my app, I have a controller that looks like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("account/orders")]
public partial class AccountOrdersController : Controller
{
  [Route]
  public virtual ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }

  [Route("add")]
  [Route("~/dashboard/orders/{orderId}/item")]
  public virtual ActionResult Add(string orderId)
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

In the Index view, I am referencing the Add action like this:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Add", "AccountOrdersController", new RouteValueDictionary(new { orderId = "xyz" }))';
```

When the view gets rendered, the above becomes:

```
var url = '/account/orders/add?orderId=xyz';
```

How do I get the above to be rendered as:

```
var url = '/account/orders/xyz/item';
```

I'm trying to create a URL that is a complete path instead of just appending query string parameters.

Answer (score 1):

When applying multiple routes your can set the order the route is applied using the `Order` property on the `[Route]` attribute. By default, all defined routes have a `Order` value of `0` and routes are processed from lowest to highest.

```
[Route("add", Order = 2)]
[Route("~/dashboard/orders/{orderId}/item", Order = 1)]
public virtual ActionResult Add(string orderId){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC always short-circuits routes. The `/account/orders/add` route is perfectly valid, since the query string is arbitrary: it can just stuff whatever was leftover into that. If you want a more complex route on an action that has a simpler route, then your only option is to name the route and get it specifically by name:

```
[Route("~/dashboard/orders/{orderId}/item", Name="DashboardOrderAdd")]
```

Then:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("DashboardOrderAdd", new { orderId = "xyz" })
```